# Algorithme cobol - Occurences

Tags: cobol

I need to count occurrences number in a file, can someone help please?

Let suppose that is my cobol file

```
A blabla 123 05/05/19
A blabla 223 05/05/19
E blabla 153 05/05/19
C blabla 110 05/05/19
C blabla 185 05/05/19
B blabla 963 05/05/19
C blabla 743 05/05/19
```

I expect to have this :

You have 2 of A, 1 of E , 3 of C and 1 B.

Comment: Think about using an array, where each entry is a group-level item with two parts: the letter that you have matched, and a counter.

Answer (score 2):

I defined two table, one for letters and one for counts. I used `SEARCH ALL` to match the letter and used that index to add to the appropriate count. Because I knew there were no invalid values in the file, I wrote the `AT END` phrase to use `CONTINUE'

I also added a line giving the total count of first letters (lines) read.

For testing of this program, I took a text file of over 2,000 characters. Used Notepad++ to give one character per line and convert all letters to uppercase. I then filtered the file to remove all punctuation and spaces.

Modify as needed.

---

```
   environment division.
   input-output section.
   file-control.
       select in-file assign "in.txt"
           organization line sequential
           .
       select out-file assign "out.txt"
           organization line sequential
           .
   data division.
   file section.
   fd in-file.
   1 in-rec pic x(8).
   fd out-file.
   1 out-rec.
    2 out-letter pic x.
    2 pic x.
    2 out-count pic zzz9.
   working-storage section.
   1 letter-table value "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".
    2 letters pic x occurs 26
       ascending key letters indexed ltr-idx.
   1 count-table.
    2 letter-count pic 9(4) binary occurs 26 indexed lc-idx.
   1 pic 9 value 0.
     88 eof value 1.
   procedure division.
   begin.
       initialize count-table
       open input in-file
           output out-file
       perform until eof
           read in-file
           at end set eof to true
           not end
               search all letters
               at end continue
               when letters(ltr-idx) = in-rec(1:1)
                   set lc-idx to ltr-idx
                   add 1 to letter-count(lc-idx)
               end-search
           end-read
       end-perform
       perform varying ltr-idx from 1 by 1
       until ltr-idx > 26
           move letters(ltr-idx) to out-letter
           set lc-idx to ltr-idx
           move letter-count(lc-idx) to out-count
           write out-rec
       end-perform
       write out-rec from spaces
       compute out-count = function sum(letter-count(all))
       write out-rec
       close in-file out-file
       stop run
       .
```

---

Output:

```
A  141
B   32
C   81
D   60
E  206
F   53
G   19
H   77
I  174
J    1
K    8
L   88
M   38
N  114
O  142
P   49
Q    1
R  108
S  143
T  193
U   49
V   28
W   29
X    2
Y   35
Z    3

  1874
```

Answer (score 0):

A JCL SORT SUM will probably do it easier if you are purely looking for the counts of record with that initial identifying character..
Sort card will be like

INREC FIELDS=(1,1,2:C'000001') SORT FIELDS=(1,1,CH,A) SUM FIELDS=(2,6,ZD)

Assuming each occurrence is less than a million; adjust that INREC and SUM FIELDS otherwise

The result should be A000123, B002323 ...